# rename page name in powerbi authoring experience for embed using javascript

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to find javascript api to rename page title in embed view.
I referred this documentation but didnt see a rename page name option. https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Page-Operations

if it is supported, can you please help with how we can modify it in embed view with api?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Power BI Embedded don't have page rename API. However, it is on our roadmap.

You can add/vote for an idea here: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/